# Mutt send mail with variable not work

Tags: bash, email

I have this code for send mail, but not work in a new server ubuntu 16.04.
while in another server it works perfectly with the "mail" command

```
mail_body_file=$(sed -n '9,$p' mail.txt > va.null)
mail_body=va.null
for fullname in HOTFOLDER/*.xlsx; do
    filename="${fullname##*/}"
    mail=$(awk -F ',' -v var="$text" '$1==var {print $2,$3}

 mutt  -s "Subject" -a "$fullname" < "$mail_body" -- "$mail"
```

↑↑↑code above no work↑↑↑

Because in a **terminal linux** is ok? :

```
mutt -s "Subject" -a foo.xlsx < mail.txt -- foo@foo.com
```

↓↓↓code below works fine with attachment in old server ubuntu 10.04 but not in new server 16.04 (attachment nothing)↓↓↓

```
mail_body_file=$(sed -n '9,$p' mail.txt > va.null)
mail_body=va.null
for fullname in HOTFOLDER/*.xlsx; do
    filename="${fullname##*/}"
    mail=$(awk -F ',' -v var="$text" '$1==var {print $2,$3}

mail  -s "Subject" -a "$fullname" "$mail" < "$mail_body"
```

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but you have a for-loop without the closing 'done' statement.

Comment: Try adding the attachment at the end of your `mutt` command like so: `mutt -s "Subject" < "$mail_body" "$mail" -a "$fullname"` as per `man mutt`  : `-a file [...]  The -a option  must be placed at the end of command line options.`.

Comment: @AnythingIsFine nothing, not work! :(

Comment: @Roadowl this is a part of code...you focuses on the mutt code only, this is a strange